# How to know if webservices are JAX WS or JAX RPC

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, jax-rpc

I have an EAR file deployed on WAS 6.1. The EAR file contains several EJB methods exposed as Web services. Now is there a way to figure out if these web services are written according to JAX WS standard or JAX RPC standard?

Answer (score 1):

Its should be JAX-RPC because first up JAX-RPC maps to Java 1.4 JAX-WS maps to Java 5.0 and WAS 6.1 has java 1.4.